# Dart: spread operator for constructor

Tags: constructor, properties, dart, flutter, spread-syntax

In my **flutter** app, I have widgets like below:

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.red,
      width: 2,
      style: BorderStyle.solid,
    ),
  ),
  child: Text('Container 1'),
)
```

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border(
      top: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: 2,
        style: BorderStyle.solid,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  child: Text('Container 2'),
)
```

Both use the same **properties** for their **borders**. So I was wondering if there's a ***spread-operator***-like way of inserting the same properties for both widgets? Maybe like:

```dart
const borderBase = (
  color: Colors.red,
  width: 2,
  style: BorderStyle.solid,
)

Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      ...borderBase,
    ),
  ),
  child: Text('Container 1'),
)

Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border(
      top: BorderSide(
        ...borderBase,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  child: Text('Container 2'),
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const BorderSide borderBase = BorderSide(
  color: Colors.red,
  width: 2,
  style: BorderStyle.solid,
);

Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      color: borderBase.color,
      width: borderBase.width,
      style: borderBase.style,
    ),
  ),
  child: Text('Container 1'),
)

Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border(
      top: borderBase,
    ),
  ),
  child: Text('Container 2'),
)
```

Not the best but still some reuse.

Comment: But this way I get errors in the `borderBase` variable saying `Undefined name 'color'`, and other **linter** errors.

Comment: Oh, I think you meant the `borderBase` **var** should use the `BorderSide()` **class**, right? Cause that seems to work.

Answer (score 10):

There is no such thing.

A spread operator is in development, but it is only for lists, not classes (https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/47)

Comment: I see. So ther's no way to re-use the same properties dynamically? Meaning I have to repeat them everytime?

Comment: Yes, you're forced to. But you can discuss about it on the issue. I think this is an interesting feature too.

Comment: 2022 - ZzZzzzzZzZzz

Answer (score 4):

Now that dart has both the spread operator and [class extensions](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/future-releases/static-extension-methods/feature-specification.md), you could abuse both to add `...spread` support to `static` methods. While **I doubt this is a good idea**, I made a working [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/bd1bfd3352ba3f9679789121bfce81ef) ([gist](https://gist.github.com/micimize/bd1bfd3352ba3f9679789121bfce81ef)) to demonstrate. The end result looks something like:

```dart
final Border spreadBorder = Border.fromSides([
  ...Border(
    left: BorderSide(color: Colors.pink),
    right: BorderSide(color: Colors.pinkAccent),
  ).sides,
  ...Border(
    top: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
    bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent),
  ).sides,
]).scale(5);

enum _Side { top, right, bottom, left }

extension SpreadBorder on Border {
  Iterable<MapEntry<_Side, BorderSide>> get sides {
    return () sync* {
      if (top != BorderSide.none) {
        yield MapEntry(_Side.top, top);
      }
      // ...other yields
    }();
  }

  static Border fromSides(Iterable<MapEntry<_Side, BorderSide>> parts) {
    BorderSide top, right, bottom, left;

    for (final borderPart in parts) {
      switch (borderPart.key) {
        case _Side.top:
          top = borderPart.value;
          break;
        // ... other cases
      }
    }
    return Border(
      top: top,
      right: right,
      bottom: bottom,
      left: left,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a dummy sample of my poor man's spread operator pattern:

I make a copy constructor for classes often re-created with slight modifications.
It is extra work during definition, but it pays off at many locations when using these classes. The same pattern can be used on standard classes by subclassing -- just to connect to the specific question.

```
class Address {
    final String street;
    final String city;
    final String state;

    Address({this.street, this.city, this.state});

    Address.copy(Address copy, {
        String street,
        String city,
        String state,
    }) : this (
        street: street ?? copy.street,
        city: city ?? copy.city,
        state: state ?? copy.state,
    );
}

class User {
    final String firstName;
    final String lastName;
    final Address address;
    final String email;

    User({this.firstName, this.lastName, this.address, this.email});

    User.copy(User copy, {
        String firstName,
        String lastName,
        Address address,
        String email,
    }) : this (
        firstName: firstName ?? copy.firstName,
        lastName: lastName ?? copy.lastName,
        address: address ?? copy.address,
        email: email ?? copy.email,
    );
}

void workWithUsers(User user) {
    final userChangedEmail = User.copy(user, email: 'new@email.com');
    final userMovedToAnotherStreet = User.copy(user, address: Address.copy(user.address, street: 'Newstreet'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The spread operator will work on Maps e.g. `Map<String, dynamic>` so what worked for me was to convert the object to json which is `Map<String, dynamic>`, use the spread operator and then convert back to the object.

You can try something like this:

```
class Something {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  
  Something({required this.id, required this.name});

  factory Something.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic?> json){
    return Something(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name']
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic?> toJson() {
    return {
    'id': id,
    'name': name
    };
  }

}


final x = Something(id: 'abc', name: 'def');
final y = Something.fromJson({...x.toJson(), 'name': 'somethingElse'})
```

This might be very expensive to do, but if all you care about is using the spread operator, this should do the job.